# Failed to install phonegap-plugin-push in ios cordova 8.0

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins

I have created a new package in Cordova 8.0 and installed all the plugins.

when adding an android platform its fine. 
But when add iOS firebase-analytics and phonegap-push plugins are not installing

Either this or that only installing

If I remove phonegap-push and add pod install its added. 
Or else remove firebase then add phone-gap pod is installing.

when using both plugins second one was not installing its says

[image: error msg screenshot]

Even I tried pod update, pod install, platform remove & add, plugin remove & add all the scenarios. 
Does anybody have an idea please update.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the issue that [my pull request](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/pull/2503) solves. Firebase implementations are not consistent across plugins and tend to introduce these easily avoidable errors.

The pull request has not been accepted yet, so proceed like this:

- Uninstall the push  plugin
- Download it anywhere and [edit the same files I have edited](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/pull/2503/files)
- Install the plugin from the path of your local copy.

Also, if you prefer you can remove the iOS platform instead, then edit the plugin files from your project's folder, then re-add the platform. This will install the newly edited plugin with your changes included, and hopefully, without the errors.

I have fixed the [incompatibility between Firebase Auth and Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2502) by editing the files exactly as show, then removing and re-adding the iOS platform. If this solves your problem kindly send a positive feedback on the Issue tracker so the PR is accepted sooner. It's been already added to the 3.0.0 milestones.

Comment: Thank you andreszs, 
i have tried that way 
Plugin.xml like this only showing
   <framework src="Firebase/Core" type="podspec" spec="~> 5.0"/>
how can i do, and still same problem